# Zebra printer uploading PCX instead of GRF image

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have two different Zebra printers, the RW420 and the iMZ320.

I am trying to print images on them.

I am using the Java/Android SDK provided by Zebra to first upload the image.

```
 printer.storeImage("R:IMAGE.GRF", ZebraImageFactory.getImage(bmp), ImageUtils.IMAGE_DIMEN, ImageUtils.IMAGE_DIMEN);
```

On the iMZ320, the image uploads just fine and I am able to print it out.

However, on the RW420, I cannot print the image and when I print the config page with the list of file names, the file is listed as 'IMAGE.PCX'

The printer's language is set to 'ZPL'

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it depends upon how you created '`printer`' in your example. If you used the `ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(Connection connection)` call directly, the SDK will communicate with the printer and determine the type of printer based on a few criteria. For RW420 it will use CPCL as the default language of choice (even though it is in ZPL mode) which will force it to use PCX rather than GRF.

To override this, you can create the printer using the explicit language you wish to use.

```
ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(PrinterLanguage.ZPL, connection);
```